# How make decent code with classes out of this [Swift]

Tags: swift, macos, class, orsserialport

I'm making an OSX app to control a device over serial, for which I'm using the ORSSerialPort library. But I've got some troubles with coding. I'm (very) new to coding and I have no idea how to properly code, which causes some problems when trying to make something work. I'll show my three 'classes' and I'll describe the function of them and then the problems I run into.

The main class, to which the library delegate is connected and from which I do all communication with the serial device (AE20125Controller.swift)

```
import Cocoa
import ORSSerial

class AE20125Controller:NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {

    var buffer = String()
    var dataProcessor = DataProcessor()

    var availablePorts = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager().availablePorts

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedPort: NSPopUpButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var connectedLogo: NSStackView!

    var serialPort: ORSSerialPort? {
        didSet {
            oldValue?.close()
            oldValue?.delegate = nil
            serialPort?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    //Actions
    @IBAction func onOpenOrClose(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let port = self.serialPort {
            if (port.open) {
                closePort(port)

            } else {
                openPort(port)
            }
        }
    }

    //Functions
    func sendData(command: String) -> Bool {
        if let data = command.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            self.serialPort?.sendData(data)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func closePort(port: ORSSerialPort){
        port.close()
        self.connectButton.title = "Verbinden"
        self.connectedLogo.hidden = true
    }

    func openPort(port: ORSSerialPort){
        port.baudRate = 9600
        port.open()
        sendData("201:T:0:;") //Gets all settings form the device
        self.connectedLogo.hidden = false
        self.connectButton.title = "Verbreken"
    }

    //Delegate
    func serialPort(serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            var message: String

            //Assemble the full data (Data come's in in parts)
            buffer.appendContentsOf(string as String)
            if(buffer.containsString(dataProcessor.endToken)){
                let i = buffer.rangeOfString(dataProcessor.startToken)?.startIndex
                let j = buffer.rangeOfString(dataProcessor.endToken)?.endIndex

                if((i != nil) && (j != nil)){
                    message = buffer[Range(start: i!, end: j!)]
                    buffer.removeRange(Range(start: i!, end: j!))

                    if(message != "" /*message != "201:U:0:;"*/){
                        dataProcessor.sortIncomingData(message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        serialPort.close()
    }

}
```

The Dataprocessor class, in which all possible messages are stored and form which I want to assemble the to be send data and all the current settings (DataProcessor.swift)

```
import Foundation

class DataProcessor {

    enum dataType: String {
        case frequency = "A"
        case waveform = "B"
        case mode = "C"
        case pllReferenceEnabled = "D"
        case pllFactor = "E"
        case pllOffset = "F"
        case startUpWavefrom = "G"
        case startUpFrequency = "H"
        case calibrationOffset = "I"
        case sweepStartFrequency = "J"
        case sweepStopFrequency = "K"
        case sweepFrequency = "L"
        case modulationType = "M"
        case fskFrequency = "N"
        case pskPhase = "O"
        case modulationSource = "P"
        case internalModulationFrequency = "Q"
        case sweepMode = "R"
        case getSettings = "T"
        case keepAlive = "U"
        case returnFromSweepMod = "V"
        case hardwareRevison = "X"
        case firmwareVersion = "Y"
        case productID = "Z"
        case present1Freq = "1"
        case present1Waveform = "2"
        case present2Freq = "3"
        case present2Waveform = "4"
        case present3Freq = "5"
        case present3Waveform = "6"
        case present4Freq = "7"
        case present4Waveform = "8"
        case present5Freq = "9"
        case present5Waveform = "0"

        func getWritable() -> Bool {
            switch self {
            case .frequency, .waveform, .mode, .pllReferenceEnabled, .pllFactor, .pllOffset, .startUpWavefrom, .startUpFrequency, .calibrationOffset, .sweepStartFrequency, .sweepStopFrequency, .sweepFrequency, .modulationType, .fskFrequency, .pskPhase, .modulationSource, .internalModulationFrequency,.sweepMode, .getSettings, .returnFromSweepMod, .present1Freq, .present1Waveform,.present2Freq,.present2Waveform, .present3Freq, .present3Waveform, .present4Freq, .present4Waveform, .present5Freq, .present5Waveform:
                return true

            default:
                return false
            }
        }

        func getReadable() -> Bool {
            switch self {
            case .frequency, .waveform, .mode, .pllReferenceEnabled, .pllFactor, .pllOffset, .startUpWavefrom, .startUpFrequency, .calibrationOffset, .sweepStartFrequency, .sweepStopFrequency, .sweepFrequency, .modulationType, .fskFrequency, .pskPhase, .modulationSource, .internalModulationFrequency, .sweepMode, .keepAlive, .hardwareRevison, .firmwareVersion, .productID:
                return true

            default:
                return false
            }

        }

       func getMaxValues() -> Int{
            switch self {
            case .frequency:
                return 10000000
            case .waveform:
                return 3
            case .mode:
                return 3
            case .pllReferenceEnabled:
                return 2
            case .pllFactor:
                return 9999
            case .pllOffset:
                return 10000000
            case .startUpWavefrom:
                return 3
            case .startUpFrequency:
                return 10000000
            case .calibrationOffset:
                return 10000
            case .sweepStartFrequency:
                fallthrough
            case .sweepStopFrequency:
                return 10000000
            case .sweepFrequency:
                return 100
            case .modulationType:
                return 2
            case .fskFrequency:
                return 10000000
            case .pskPhase:
                return 3599
            case .modulationSource:
                return 2
            case .internalModulationFrequency:
                return 10000
            case .sweepMode:
                return 2
            case .getSettings:
                return 0
            case .returnFromSweepMod, .present1Freq, .present2Freq, .present3Freq, .present4Freq, .present5Freq:
                return 10000000
            case .present1Waveform, .present2Waveform, .present3Waveform, .present4Waveform, .present5Waveform:
                return 3

            default:
                return -1
            }
        }
    }


    let endToken = ":;"
    let startToken = "201:"

    var settings:[(dataType):(String)] = [:]

    //Methodes
    func sortIncomingData(data: String){
        let i = data.rangeOfString(startToken)?.endIndex
        let j = data.rangeOfString(endToken)?.startIndex

        let sortedCode = data.substringWithRange(Range(start: i!, end: i!.advancedBy(1)))
        let sortedData = data.substringWithRange(Range(start: i!.advancedBy(2), end: j! ))

        settings[dataType(rawValue: sortedCode)!] = sortedData

    }

    func setData(data: dataType, value: Float){
        settings.updateValue(String(value), forKey: data)
        AE20125Controller.sendData(...) //<-- Is not working (Ignore the     dots)

    }
}
```

The menuItems class, which should handle all the changes and actions in the GUI. (MenuItems.swift)

```
import Cocoa

class MenuItems:NSObject{
    @IBOutlet weak var freqView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var test: NSTextField!

    //Actions
    @IBAction func setFreq(sender: AnyObject) {

    }


}
```

I left out the AppDelegate since there is nothing in it, but the settings in order to construct the view (ex. change the background of the view's to white).

I'm unable to communicate between the classes, for example I need to send the data using the sendData method in AE20125Controller class in the DataProcessor class, but i need to initiate it. But the DataProcessor class is initiated in the AE20125Controller class? This also applies to the MenuItems class, when the updateFreq button is pressed, the method setData in the DataProcessor class should be called, but I need to initiate it.

To be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing, how to properly this system, so that everything works, without putting everything in one file, so that i can keep it organized. Again, I'm new to programming, but (if I may say so myself) I do have some knowledge in programming. Please help me organise my (crappy) code and give me some tips in how to avoid this in future things.

(If you know a good Advanced Swift OSX programming guide/Course, please tell me. (It doesn't have to be free))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

An way to communicate between different parts in your app is with the NSNotificationCenter. Check here for the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Edit: In this case I would suggest to make a singleton for your communication:

```
class Communicator:NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {
    class let sharedInstance = Communicator()
}
```

so you can call:

```
Communicator.sharedInstance.sendData(...)
```

Comment: Any Explanation on how? Like Examples

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is likely not the right choice here.See for example: https://davidnix.io/post/stop-using-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: You are probably right, I edited my post with a better way.